# How to fire an event when something changes in database to clients in web server using node js

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

I want to send a notification to the connected clients of my webserver when value changes in mongo database using node js .
Just like firebase database does.
What's the mechanism of such approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebSocket, a long polling AJAX connection or an abstraction layer like Socket.io or a plain TCP connection in native apps. There are also HTML5 Server-Sent Events that you could use for hybrid apps of a web view. The message should be sent from your backend and it has to be handled on the frontend. Search for pub/sub, message queues, real time communication, SSE and event handling in the frontend framework that you're using on the client side. It's impossible to tell you any more details as an answer to such a general question. You will have to search info on the technologies and techniques mentioned above. There are also entire real time frameworks like ActionHero that can handle a lot of those things for you. And there are full stack frameworks like Meteor that handles the database synchronization for you as well. See:

- https://www.actionherojs.com/

You should be able to use it with native and hybrid apps with no problem -  it handles TCP, WebSocket and HTTP connections - but this is just an example, there are more frameworks that you can use and of course you can also use no framework at all if you want to code all ofthe communication logic yourself. It's up to you.